# result of IF statement on NULL

Tags: sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server 2008.  My current script has SET ANSI_NULLS ON (i.e., if a comparison operates on an expression that is NULL, then the comparison returns UNKNOWN, not TRUE or FALSE).  Does an IF statement execute the T-SQL batch following it only when the IF statement returns TRUE?  Or, can it execute when the IF statement returns UNKNOWN as well?

As a test case, I'm trying to determine what happens in the following IF statement:

```
IF CONVERT(varchar(10), @some_date, 101) = '01/01/1900'
do things
```

As far as I know, "do things" will only execute if the given IF statement returns TRUE.  So, as an example, if @some_date = '01/01/1901', then the IF statement returns FALSE, which means "do things" wouldn't execute.  As another example, if @some_date is NULL, the CONVERT would return NULL as well (I think), which means NULL would (try to) be compared against '01/01/1900', which means the IF statement would return UNKNOWN (because ANSI_NULLS is ON).  Since UNKNOWN is not TRUE, then "do things" wouldn't execute.  Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: The comparison of (NULL = anything) is always false.

Comment: Is there a question behind this question?  because so far this is a question you can answer by testing it yourself.

Comment: Yes, null is treated as false in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the coalesce() function to replace NULL with a known value.

Also, since your value is already a date, you'll do better treating the constant `1/1/1900` as a date than you will converting `@some_value` to a string.

```
--assuming @some_date is actually a datetime, and you only want to compare the date portion
If coalesce(cast(@some_date as date), '1900-01-01') = '1900-01-01'
Begin
    -- do something
End
```

Also, you can test this yourself. Look at the following code:

```
--set ansi_nulls off
declare @some_date datetime; 

--set @some_date = '01/01/1900'

If convert(varchar(10), @some_date, 101) = '01/01/1900'
    print 'True'
```

Try it in Sql Server Management Studio both with and without the commented lines, and observe the results.

Comment: I'm not looking to change the code.  I'm just trying to determine what happens when @some_date is NULL.

Comment: Maybe you should be. Or, put another way, if you only wanted to know what happens, why not just run a test through management studio?

Comment: I tried it out in SSMS.  Changing ANSI_NULLS has no effect on @some_date being NULL or '01/01/1900'.  This must mean that the T-SQL after an IF statement only executes when IF returns TRUE.

Comment: It's worth pointing out this statement from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx): **`SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison.`** The `Convert()` function call here makes this equivalent to a compound expression.